# Ajax call to ASP.NET WebMethod not hitting server side method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm trying to pass a single parameter to my code behind. I'm reaching the success end of ajax but the method in my aspx.cs code behind doesn't get called. I'm using a masterfile if it makes a difference.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var someID = "";
    $('.glyphicon-trash').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fileName.aspx/deleteSomething",
            data: "{'deleteSomeID':'" + someID + "'}", // someID is assigned to a value by another button
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("success"); // this alert works.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

fileName.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //... stuff here
}

[WebMethod]
public static void deleteSomething(string deleteSomeID)
{
    MySqlDbUtilities db = new MySqlDbUtilities();
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    string sql = "DELETE FROM Targets WHERE targetID = @someID";
    cmd = db.GetCommand(sql);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someID", deleteSomeID);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    db.Dispose();
}
```

The "someID" is filled when you click a button on the page. That is working properly, I triple checked. The method however doesn't do anything. I don't know if it's being reached either. Any ideas?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the method's signature to see if it's being hit or not

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I put a breakpoint on the method signature and it was not hit. That's interesting.

Comment: Do you see any errors at browser's console? (F12)

Comment: @zed no errors in console

Comment: You could try to pass the data in another non-JSON format, in case you might not have the JSON parser enabled (not sure if possible)

Comment: Try encoding your JSON data, like this: `data: JSON.stringify({ deleteSomeID: someID })`

Comment: @cFrozenDeath
I tried this:
    var postData = {};
                    postData.ruleID = ruleID;
    
                    $.post("RuleBuilderSean.aspx/deleteRule",     postData).done(function (data) {
                        console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
                     });

same problem. No errors. One thing I was able to learn from this was that "data" is passing my entire html code. I'm pretty sure it should be null though because I didn't return anything

Comment: is 'msg' anything? In your success handler, is this an empty string?
In MVC we often return JsonResult from ajax methods - I'll update my answer with something.

Comment: You could try to download a browser (Chrome/Firefox) plugin like a Rest client, host the app and try to hit the method from the plugin. See if the method gets hit or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not build up the `data` parameter manually, instead make a proper encoding by using `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fileName.aspx/deleteSomething",
    data: JSON.stringify({ deleteSomeID: someID }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Also, you may handle the scenario where your query could throw an exception, and act accordingly in your UI, a very simple way of do this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string deleteSomething(string deleteSomeID)
{
    try {
        MySqlDbUtilities db = new MySqlDbUtilities();
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        string sql = "DELETE FROM Targets WHERE targetID = @someID";
        cmd = db.GetCommand(sql);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someID", deleteSomeID);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        db.Dispose();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return e.Message;
    }

    return "1";
}
```

Then, manage the response at success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fileName.aspx/deleteSomething",
    data: JSON.stringify({ deleteSomeID: someID }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == "1") {
            alert("Successful deletion");
        } else {
            alert("Operation failed! Details: " + response);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data: param looks wrong to me. You don't need it to be a string.

UPDATE: You say you hit the success handler - just for completeness can you add this error handler and double check it is not hit?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var someID = "";
        $('.glyphicon-trash').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "fileName.aspx/deleteSomething",
                data: { deleteSomeID: someID },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("success"); // this alert works.
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, text) {
                  console.log(xhr.status);
                  console.log(xhr.text);
                  console.log(xhr.responseText);
                 }
            });
        });
```

I'm more used to MVC, so I cannot guarantee JsonResult works in webforms (I'd be surprised if not though).

Change your webmethod to return a JsonResult.

In your code, declare a bool set to false, and set it to true after your SQL execution. Return the following:

```
JsonResult returnObj = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                wasSuccessful = myBool,
            },
            ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
        };

        return Json(returnObj);
```

Change your success handler:

```
success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data.wasSuccessful);
        }
```

Comment: I didn't think it would work without being a string. Thanks. But, it's still giving me the same problem. +1  anyways

Comment: I'm still hitting success after adding in your error handling.

Comment: @user3044394 you're receiving "msg" in your success function when your method returns **void**. You should either return something else in your function or remove "msg" from the AJAX call